# Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input' angular 9 and different modules

Tags: angular, ngmodel

Hello everyone,
I know there are many questions about the title error message and I spent several hours to solve the error but I don't find the solution yet. I'm using angular 9 and I have 2 modules such one is appModule and userModule. I imported Forms Module in both of module files and it does not work.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="user.name" placeholder="user.name" name="username"/>
```

The ngModel from the above code line give me the error message.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { FormsModule  } from '@angular/forms';

import { UserRoutingModule } from './user-routing/user-routing.module';

@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    
 ],
 imports: [
   CommonModule,
   FormsModule,
   UserRoutingModule

 ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

This is the user.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { UserListComponent } from '../user-list/user-list.component';
import { UserDetailComponent } from '../user-detail/user-detail.component';

const usersRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: UserListComponent },
  { path: 'user/:id', component: UserDetailComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UserListComponent,
    UserDetailComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(usersRoutes),
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class UserRoutingModule { }
```

This is the user-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => import('./users/users.module').then(m => m.UsersModule)     
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'users',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

This is the app-routing.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { UsersModule } from './users/users.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    UsersModule,
    AppRoutingModule
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is the app.module.ts

I don't get the error when I use these code using in one module and this error message get when I separate two modules.
Any ideas to solve the problem and thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Move your declarations from user-routing.module.ts to user.module.ts

Comment: No, I can't move the declarations from user-routing.module.ts to  user.module.ts because in routes variable, components are used to point the router path.

Comment: For that you don't have to declare them in routing file , just import the components on top.
Declare the components in module file only.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the FormsModule from import in app.module.ts.
2. Add 'FormsModule' in user.module.ts under exports: [UserModule]